# IndexOf function is always returing -1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i write a indexOf function for json array always it's returning -1.

```
parent = [{'a':'hello'},{'a':'world'}];
var child = {'a':'hello'};
var index = parent.indexOf(child);
```

actually this index should be 0 but it's returning -1;

PLease help me with this issue.

Comment: `indexOf` can't compare objects like this.

Comment: I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: Bear in mind that when using the `{...}` notation, you are implicitly creating a **new** object, which has nothing in common with the object you previously defined, even if it has the same properties & values.
For example, try `alert({'a':'b'} == {'a' : 'b'})` in JSFiddle...
If you want to look for the very object you pushed into parent, you have to pass its reference to the `indexOf` method.
For example,

`var child = {'a':'hello'};
parent = [child,{'a':'world'}];
var index = parent.indexOf(child);`